# Set Flexbox Min Height To Fill Remaining Screen in Scrolling Container

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am moderately familiar with Flex-box, but this issue has me baffled:

I am trying to create a flex-box layout that:

1. Puts a footer at the bottom of the screen IF content is shorter than the screen (view-port)
2. Puts footer at end of scrolling content IF content is longer than the screen (view-port)

I can seem to get one, or the other, but not both of these to work. A couple of goals:

- Achieve this, if possible, in CSS alone
- The header should remain fixed at the top of the screen, while the content has scrollable overflow
- The header bar will vary in size, so the solution should accommodate
  this

[image]

[Codesandbox Demo of Issue](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-m2t15?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is this what you need?

https://codesandbox.io/s/flexbox-min-height-in-scolling-container-issue-fml96

If so, I will explain it below.

Comment: Ok. Done below. 

I also changed the background-color of #scrollingSegment but just to make it look nicer.

Comment: I previously marked this question as answered - but just realized an issues remains. With the suggested solutions so far, the header is no longer fixed (which is a requirement). This is still an open question. Apologies @awais for the false-start. I have updated the question to increase clarity on this

Comment: @arhnee Sorry for not including that earlier, i update my ans with fixed dynamic header please have a look :)

Comment: @Awais - perfect, thanks! I just marked your reply as the answer. For everyone's benefit, here is a codesandbox with the full working solution: https://codesandbox.io/embed/flexbox-min-height-in-scolling-container-issue-with-solution-7f6c0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @arhnee Sorry again as i didn't see the last requirement of you, Anyway Glad that helps ! Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `min-height` to `100vh` of `#wrapper` like

```
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

And alps you need to set `margin` of `body` to `0` to avoid scroll

```
body{
 margin: 0;
}
```

For sticky header as per OP Requirement Please add theses styles along with the above one i mentioned (i just remove height as you said header is of dynamic height)

```
#header {
    background-color: darkgray;
    /* height: 64px; */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

So the final Styles you need to put inside `demo.css` are as below

```
body {
  background-color: #444;
  margin: 0;}

#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#header {
    background-color: darkgray;
    /* height: 64px; */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it on his Codesandbox Demo? It doesn't work, breaks the layout when "Display Long Content!"'s button is clicked

Comment: @andergtk Yes i tried setting these style at top in demo.css `body {
  background-color: #444;
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height:  100vh;
}
`

Comment: @andergtk To  make it more clear for both of us Can you please update You `demo.css` with the above one so that we both can see whats happening

Comment: My mistake, i used `height` property instead `min-height`. Your answer works perfectly in add with `margin: 0` on body

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to scroll only content?. change these css only.

```
#mainContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: white;
  height:100vh;
 }

#footer {
  background-color: red;
  height: 64px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
  background-color: #444;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh
}

#footer {
  background-color: red;
  height: 64px;
  width:100%;
  left: 0;
  position:  absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution when we want our footer to be on the bottom of the screen even when the content of our flexbox wrapper is shorter than the height of our screen.

The solution is to create a div (we can call it spacer) just above the fotter and give it a css property `flex: 1` (Which is a shortcut for flex-grow:1, flex-shrink:1 and flex-basis:0). If you think about it, what we want is to make our div spacer grow or shrink with the content.

In summary, I added:

**CSS**

```
.spacer {flex: 1;} 
#wrapper {display: flex; flex-direction: column; min-height: 100vh;}
```

**TSX**

```
<div className="spacer" />
```

A complete example can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/flexbox-min-height-in-scolling-container-issue-fml96)